# Creating a single button that inputs data from a form on different worksheets based on a cells value

Tags: excel, vba, button

I am creating a asset management worksheet to show a car as signed in/out. I have different worksheets for the different vehicles. I have a single button that I would like to use to populate the form data on each worksheet depending on a single cells value.

For instance, if in the VRM cell shows as "KW1", I want the data on the form to be populated on the worksheet "KW1" when the button is pressed.

If the VRM cell shows as "TN2", I want the data on the form to be populated on the worksheet "TN2" when the same button is pressed.

I could have separate buttons for each car but as there are upwards of 20, I would like a single button to establish what the VRM cells value is and then place this information on the correct worksheet.

What I have tried:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    If Range("C6").Value = "KW1" Then
    
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim NextRow As Long
    
        Set ws1 = Worksheets("Car Booking")
        Set ws2 = Worksheets("KW1")
        NextRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 1) = Now()
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 2) = Application.UserName
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 3) = ws1.Cells(8, 3)
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 4) = ws1.Cells(5, 3)
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 5) = ws1.Cells(6, 3)
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 6) = ws1.Cells(9, 3)
        
Else

If Range("C6").Value = "TN2" Then
    
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim NextRow As Long
    
        Set ws1 = Worksheets("Car Booking")
        Set ws2 = Worksheets("TN2")
        NextRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 1) = Now()
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 2) = Application.UserName
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 3) = ws1.Cells(8, 3)
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 4) = ws1.Cells(5, 3)
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 5) = ws1.Cells(6, 3)
        ws2.Cells(NextRow, 6) = ws1.Cells(9, 3)

End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Set ws2 = Worksheets(ws1.Range("C6").Value)` and there is no need for the `if ... else`